# Selecting distinct values from table using two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

I have following data in the table.

```
Id   Name
1    Abc
2    Abc
3    Xyz
4    Xyz
5    def
6    def
```

I want following results from the query

```
Id  Name
1   Abc
2   Xyz
3   def
```

I want to avoid duplicates in the name column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Select distinct 
    id, name 
from table A
```

will not work as ids are having a different values.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense. You have ID 2 associated with Xyz, but in the source data it's associated with Abc. Similarly with ID 3 and def. What is the purpose of your query?

Comment: Are you sure that Xyz isn't supposed to be matched to 3 and Def with 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a group by instead.

```
select
  min(id), [name]
from
  tableA
group by [name]
```

Note that in your example, the ids that corresponds with `Xyz` are 3 and 4, so getting a 2 next to `Xyz` is only possible if you break the integrity of the table.  If you are just looking for an auto number next to the ids you can do this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY min(id)) id,
       name 
  FROM tableA
group by name
```

Comment: Thank you. row_number query is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your specific result using:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id)) as id, name
from table A
group by name;
```

Renumbering the rows seems strange, but `row_number()` will do that.